# Logstash ERROR: (NameError) cannot initialize Java class org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I just got both Kibana and ElasticSearch up and running as a windows service and now i want to build a very basic logstash pipeline to figure how it will perform sending the results to ElasticSearch so that i can make sure the pipeline really works well, below are my config and the error message.I also checked both kibana and ElasticSearch on browser, logging in with these credentials. Feeling stuck, any help is appreciated

## **logstash.conf**

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] index => "test.logstash" user => "elastic" password => "=Slkd9*T39wyNxw175bK" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

## **cmd commands:**

`D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\bin>logstash -f D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\bin\logstash.conf`

## **error message:**

```
"Using bundled JDK: D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\jdk\bin\java.exe"
D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/java_thread_pool_executor.rb:13: warning: method redefined; discarding old to_int
D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/java_thread_pool_executor.rb:13: warning: method redefined; discarding old to_f
[FATAL] 2024-03-14 01:17:34.844 [main] Logstash - Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (NameError) cannot initialize Java class org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
org.jruby.exceptions.NameError: (NameError) cannot initialize Java class org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage.method_missing(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:253) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at RUBY.initialize(D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:126) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.new(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:897) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at RUBY.<module:LogStash>(D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:342) ~[?:?]
        at RUBY.<main>(D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:25) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at RUBY.<main>(D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins.rb:18) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at RUBY.<main>(D:/logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.12.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:48) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:88) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaSupport.loadJavaClass(JavaSupport.java:327) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.loadJavaClass(Java.java:1033) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.loadJavaClass(Java.java:1022) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyClassOrNull(Java.java:1073) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyOrPackageUnderPackage(Java.java:964) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage.method_missing(JavaPackage.java:253) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.call(JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers$MethodMissingWrapper.call(Helpers.java:636) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:456) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:350) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:76) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:164) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:151) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:461) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:210) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:897) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:333) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:456) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:350) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:76) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.instructions.DefineModuleInstr.INTERPRET_MODULE(DefineModuleInstr.java:80) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.instructions.DefineModuleInstr.interpret(DefineModuleInstr.java:68) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.processOtherOp(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:155) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:98) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:93) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:466) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:244) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:318) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:93) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:466) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:244) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:318) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:662) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:133) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.indy.InvokeSite.performIndirectCall(InvokeSite.java:735) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.indy.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:680) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.RUBY$script(D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:88) ~[?:?]
        at D_3a_.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.run(D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:114) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:1286) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1203) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1185) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1221) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:999) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.Logstash.run(Logstash.java:163) [logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.Logstash.main(Logstash.java:73) [logstash-core.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.logstash.plugins.PluginLookup.PluginType.─░NPUT
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273) ~[?:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.PluginLookup$PluginType.valueOf(PluginLookup.java:142) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry$YamlWithChecksum.convertYamlMapToObject(AliasRegistry.java:120) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry$YamlWithChecksum.decodeYaml(AliasRegistry.java:108) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry$AliasYamlLoader.loadAliasesDefinitionsFromInputStream(AliasRegistry.java:208) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry$AliasYamlLoader.loadAliasesDefinitions(AliasRegistry.java:194) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry.<init>(AliasRegistry.java:252) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.plugins.AliasRegistry.<clinit>(AliasRegistry.java:242) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaSupport.loadJavaClass(JavaSupport.java:327) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.loadJavaClass(Java.java:1033) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.loadJavaClass(Java.java:1022) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyClassOrNull(Java.java:1073) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.Java.getProxyOrPackageUnderPackage(Java.java:964) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage.method_missing(JavaPackage.java:253) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.call(JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$method_missing.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers$MethodMissingWrapper.call(Helpers.java:636) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:456) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:350) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:76) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:164) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:151) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:461) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:210) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:897) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:333) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:456) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:195) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:350) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:76) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.instructions.DefineModuleInstr.INTERPRET_MODULE(DefineModuleInstr.java:80) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.instructions.DefineModuleInstr.interpret(DefineModuleInstr.java:68) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.processOtherOp(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:155) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:98) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:93) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:466) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:244) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:318) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:93) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:466) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:244) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:318) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:66) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(Interpreter.java:96) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:81) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:30) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.IRTranslator.execute(IRTranslator.java:42) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:1299) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:3031) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$ResourceLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:925) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LibrarySearcher$FoundLibrary.load(LibrarySearcher.java:883) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.tryLoadingLibraryOrScript(LoadService.java:682) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.lambda$smartLoadInternal$0(LoadService.java:584) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.executeAndClearLock(LoadService.java:517) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.lock(LoadService.java:481) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService$RequireLocks.access$300(LoadService.java:436) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.smartLoadInternal(LoadService.java:570) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.require(LoadService.java:423) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.requireCommon(RubyKernel.java:1078) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(RubyKernel.java:1071) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$1$0$require.gen) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:662) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:133) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.indy.InvokeSite.performIndirectCall(InvokeSite.java:735) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.targets.indy.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:680) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.RUBY$script(D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:88) ~[?:?]
        at D_3a_.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_8_dot_12_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.run(D:\logstash-8.12.2-windows-x86_64\logstash-8.12.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:114) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:1286) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1203) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1185) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:1221) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:999) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.Logstash.run(Logstash.java:163) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
        at org.logstash.Logstash.main(Logstash.java:73) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
```

uninstalled logstash and then reinstalled, but getting the same results ending up with that error